# How give style for GWT CellList in Onclick event?

Tags: gwt, uibinder, gwt2

I'm confused by the showcase [example of Cell List](http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellList). Shown below is a screenshot, when I inspect the element I can see a **png image** is used to give a blue background for the selected cell. I cannot find any reference to such an image or css file from its source code [here](http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellList) or from [google-code](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/?r=9045#svn/trunk/samples/showcase/src/com/google/gwt/sample/showcase/client/content/cell%253Fstate%253Dclosed). I couldn't find any injection of css or things like that as mentioned in related sof answers. Please show me where the code is or some other example code. I'd like to know how this exact scenario works, not an alternate solution to get the effect. I'm pretty new to gwt, I'm sure this is a piece of cake for the veterans out here,any clues?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's the default styling for the `CellList`. You can use your own by passing a `CellList.Resources` to the [`CellList` constructor](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/CellList.html#CellList%28com.google.gwt.cell.client.Cell,%20com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client.CellList.Resources%29).

Comment: Yes you are correct I got the solution, if you insist that I accept your answer then could you elaborate with sample codes. So that some other person reading this wont have to look another place to find it out, as I did... or shall I do the same and answer my own question?

Comment: I don't have sample code at hand. If you do, feel free to edit the answer (if you can; otherwise I'll try to find time to elaborate).